# A fact on C1 functions

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

Consider $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and define 
\begin{equation}
\sigma_n(f):=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)
\end{equation}
for $n=1,2,\dots$

I'm trying to prove that if $f\in C^1([0,1])$, then there exists a constant (depending on the function $f$) $a(f)$ such that
\begin{equation}
\sigma_n(f)=a+\frac{\sigma_n(f')}{2n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).
\end{equation}

I have tried to use Taylor' series about $\frac{k-1}{n}$ for $k=1,\dots,n$ but I can't figure it out...it seems to be not working...

Comment: Hints: $a=\int_0^1 f$, and $f'$ is _uniformly_ continuous.

Comment: Why should I use the uniformous continuity of $f'$?

By using your hint I get $\sigma_n(f)=\int_0^1 f- \frac{\sigma_n(f')}{2n}+ o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ ; am I wrong?

Comment: I can't say you're wrong because you don't show us the argument. I don't see how to get that $o(1/n)$ without using uniform continuity of $f'$. How do you do it, exactly?

Comment: $\int_0^1f=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_{\frac{k-1}{n}}^{\frac{k}{n}}\left( f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)+\left(x-\frac{k}{n}\right)f'\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)+o(\frac{1}{n}) \right)$ whence $\sigma_n(f)=\int_0^1f-\frac{\sigma_n(f')}{2n}+o(\frac{1}{n})$

Comment: Yes, that's wrong, at least without some explanation. Inside the sum you have that $o(1/n)$, one in each term. That denotes something that satisfies $no(1/n)\to0$. But the reason $n o(1/n)\to0$ is that $f$ is differentiable at $x-k/n$. The _rate_ at which it tends to $0$ then depends on $k$. You need that all those little $no(1/n)$'s tend to $0$ uniformly to deduce that the sum (times the coefficients) is $o(1/n)$. That uniform convergence follows if $f'$ is continuous.

Comment: I actually thought that $\sum_{k=1}^n \int_{\frac{k-1}{n}}^{\frac{k}{n}}o(\frac{1}{n})=n\frac{1}{n}o(\frac{1}{n})$ $=o \left( \frac{1}{n}\right)$ ...

Comment: The problem is that "$o(1/n)$" is not an expression that actually equals something sepcific, it denotes a sequence with a certain property. Example: Say $e_{n,j}=j^2/n^2$. Then for every $j$ it is true that $e_{n,j}=o(1/n)$. But $\frac1n\sum_{j=1}^n e_{n,j}\sim1$. So there we have ann expression that formally looks like $\frac1n\sum_{j=1}^n o(1/n)$, but which does _not_ equal $o(1/n)$.

Comment: On the other hand: Saying $e_{n,j}=o(1/n)$ means that $ne_{n,j}\to0$. If $ne_{n,j}\to0$ _uniformly_ in $j$ as $n\to\infty$ then it _does_ follows that $\frac1n\sum_{j=1}^n e_{n,j}=o(1/n)$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand: first of all your example doesn't work because $\frac{\frac{(n-1)^2}{n^2}}{\frac{1}{n}}\rightarrow \infty$ so that, for instance, $\frac{(n-1)^2}{n^2}}$ is not a little-o of $\frac{1}{n}$ and secondly, $\frac{n o(\frac{1}{n})}{\frac{1}{n}}$ could tend to infinity so that $\frac{n o(\frac{1}{n})}$ could not be a little-o of $\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: Of course $(n-1)^2/n^2$ is not $o(1/n)$. But for each fixed $j$, $j^2/n^2$ _is_ $o(1/n)$. Your point says just that the $o(1/n)$ is not uniform in $j$, and that's exactly the problem. Regarding your second comment, when I say $\to0$ I mean $\to0$. Saying $e=o(1/n)$ says exactly that $ne_n\to0$. You're right that it does not say $ne_n=o(1/n)$, but I didn;t say it did.

Comment: It seems like in your universe "$o(1/n)$" always denotes _uniform_ convergence. If the $o$ always denotes _uniform_ convergence then your original $f(k/n)-(x-k/n)f'(k/n)+o(1/n)$ is simply wrong - if we're talking about uniform convergence then you need $f'$ continuous to get that.

Comment: In my universe, "o(1/n)" means just that $\frac{o(1/n)}{1/n}\rightarrow 0$ and I think that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} o(1/n)=o(1/n)$ e.g. $1/n^2=o(1/n)$ and $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} (1/n^2)=(1/n^2)=o(1/n)$. 
What doesn't convince me in your counterexample is that in the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n}e_{n,j}$ you are considering also $e_{n,n}$ that is not an $o(1/n)$

Comment: The question is when you have several $o(1/n)$ are you assuming that that fraction tends to $0$ _uniformly_? If yes then the $o(1/n)$ in your proof is wrong (unless we assume $f'$ is continuous). If no then you cannot say that $\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^no(1/n)=o(1/n)$.

Comment: Just posted an answer giving an example of a differentiable function for which the result is _false_. Hence any proof that doesn't use continuity of $f'$ is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears from the comment thread that we have an idea how to prove the result, but there's confusion over why any correct proof must use the fact that $f'$ is continuous. First we give a counterexample: A differentiable function $f$, with $f'$ continuous except at the origin, such that the conclusion is *false*. Then for the sake of tidiness we give a proof of the result assuming $f'$ is continuous.

At first I thought about showing that the conclusion fails for the traditional $t^2\sin(1/t)$ thing, but estimating the required $\sigma_n(f)$ and $\sigma_n(f')$ for that function made my head hurt. Decided to actually write down an example when I realized the calculations could be much simplified by building $f$ out of non-decreasing functions.

Let $\phi:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be smooth and non-decreasing, with $\phi(t)=0$ for $t<-1$, $\phi(t)=1$ for $t>1$, and $\phi'(0)=1$. Let $$f_n(t)=\phi\left(100^n(t-2^{-n})\right),$$and define $$f=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 4^{-n}f_n.$$

First, $f$ is certainly continuous, so $$\sigma_n(f)\to\int_0^1f(t)\,dt.$$

Note that $f_n'=0$ on $\Bbb R\setminus I_n$, where $I_n=(2^{-n}-100^{-n},2^{-n}+100^{-n})$. Since the $I_n$ are disjoint it is clear that $f$ is differentiable except perhaps at the origin where the $I_n$ pile up, and that in fact $f'$ is continuous away from the origin. Now $$0\le f_n\le\chi_{[2^{-n}-100^{-n},\infty)};$$this shows that $$0\le f(t)\le ct^2$$near the origin, so $f$ is differentiable at the origin. So $f$ is differentiable.

Since $f_n'\ge0$ it follows that $$\sigma_{2^n}(f')\ge 2^{-n}f'(2^{-n})
\ge 8^{-n}f_n'(2^{-n})=(100/8)^n.$$So $$2^{-n}\sigma_{2^n}(f')\to\infty,$$showing that $\lim\frac1{2n}\sigma_n(f')$ does not exist.

---

**Proof, using continuity of $f'$:**

Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $f'$ is uniformly continuous there exists $N$ such that $$|f'(t)-f'(s)|<\epsilon\quad(|t-s|<1/N).$$

Assume that $n>N$. Let $a=\int_0^1 f(t)\,dt$. Now

$$\sigma_n(f)-a=\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{(k-1)/n}^{k/n}(f(k/n)-f(t))\,dt.$$If $t\in[(k-1)/n,k/n]$ then $$\begin{align}f(k/n)-f(t)&=\int_t^{k/n}f'(s)\,ds
\\&=(k/n-t) f'(k/n)+\int_t^{k/n}(f'(s)-f'(k/n))\,ds\\&=(k/n-t)f'(k/n)+E_{n,k}(t),\end{align}$$where
$$|E_{n,k}(t)|<\frac\epsilon n.$$So $$\int_{(k-1)/n}^{k/n} (f(k/n)-f(t))
=\frac1{2n^2}f'(k/n)+\int_{(k-1)/n}^{k/n}E_{n,k}(t)\,dt.$$Inserting this above shows that $$\sigma_n(f)-a=\frac1{2n}\sigma_n(f')+\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{(k-1)/n}^{k/n}E_{n,k}(t)\,dt$$and$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{(k-1)/n}^{k/n}E_{n,k}(t)\,dt\right|<\frac\epsilon n.$$

Comment: I have accepted your answer but, to be honest, I accept just the second part; your counter-example still doesn't prove anything because my argument uses Taylor's theorem which needs the continuity of the derivative to be applied.
Nevertheless, I am almost convinced you are right: the uniformous continuity is necessary.

Comment: @WilliamTomblin "my argument uses Taylor's theorem which needs the continuity of the derivative to be applied" If you _realize_ that your argument needs continuity of $f'$ then why were you insisting you didn't need continuity? The argument proves that continuity is needed. "Nevertheless, I am almost convinced you are right: the uniformous continuity is necessary" : ??? You know continuity is required and you're "almost convinced" that uniform continuity is needed? Huh? Surely you realize that since $f'$ is defined on $[0,1]$ continuity is _equivalent_ to uniform continuity?